# OpenGL support in windows 8 store Application C#

Tags: c#, opengl, windows-8, opengl-es, windows-store-apps

Is OpenGL and OpenGL ES available for Windows 8 Store Application (want to run application in windows 8 pro tablet)?

and yes then it is available in C#?

(This above question is because i want chroma key composting "green screen" implement in windows 8 pro using OpenGL)

Comment: OpenGL is available in C# via OpenTK (or Tao or SharpGL, but I personally prefer OpenTK), but Microsoft restricted the Windows Store to only allow DirectX (not even XNA, though IIRC SharpDX/MonoGame found a way around that)

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Open Technologies are working on OpenGL ES support for Windows Store.

https://github.com/MSOpenTech/angle

It's written in C++.

Answer (score 2):

Please find answer from here [MSDN FORUMS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/29af68aa-7283-44ba-bb11-0e462d6f6d58/opengl-support-in-windows-8-store-application-c)

> DirectX is available to Windows Store apps. OpenGL is not. How best to
>   perform a green screen will depend on what sort of green screen you
>   need. For advanced graphics you generally want DirectX, but for simple
>   static greenscreening you can access a WriteableBitmap's PixelBuffer
>   directly.
>   --Rob